# print formatting in python 3

Tags: python, printing, python-3.x

I am trying to print in Python 3 and am having trouble. I have a for loop in my code that looks like this:

```
seq = input("enter DNA sequence to search: ")
pat = re.compile('(.{10})(ATC.{3,6}CAG)')
li = []
output_lines = [] 
for mat in pat.finditer(seq):
    x = mat.end()
    li.append(mat.groups()+(seq[x:x+10],))
for u in li:
    z = u[1] 
    A = z.count('A')
    C = z.count('C') 
    G = z.count('G') 
    T = z.count('T')
    sumbases = [A,C,G,T]
    print(sumbases)
```

When I print `sumbases`, I get this for example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 0, 1, 4]
```

I am trying to format the output like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4],[2, 0, 1, 4]
```

Can anyone show me the problem?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's *not* the output from this code. It'll print precisely `A,C,G,T` and a newline per iteration. I'd prefer if you posted your real code, or at least were consistent with the examples.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't include the entire code. I can see how the question is unclear.

Comment: @delnan i edited my post to include the entire code.

Comment: You should consider using the built-in optimized `collections.Counter` facility.

Comment: Seems the intent of `li.append(mat.groups()+(seq[x:x+10],))` is to also capture the following ten characters, why not just add a third capture group to explicitly match them: `'(.{10})(ATC.{3,6}CAG)(.{10})'` . Then I think you can simply write `li = re.findall(pat, seq)` ...

Comment: ...or in fact you could simply reduce everything to: `Counter([ u for mat in ['ABCD','DDBD','CADC'] for u in mat ]).values()`.

Comment: But (cc: @EricLebigot), `Counter` does not return explicit zero counts, it simply skips absent values, hence using `z.count()` is probably the way to go, like you did. Although I'd delegate that base-pair counting code to a helper function `get_base_pair_count()` for clarity.

Comment: Also it would help if you would edit some sample input value for `seq` into your code, to make this reproducible for the rest of us.

Comment: `count()` called 4 times is about 4 times as slow as `Counter()`. Getting zero counts from a counter can then be done easily: `Counter(…)["A"]` returns 0 if A wasn't found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
output_lines = []
for u in li:  
    z = u[1]  
    A = z.count('A')  
    C = z.count('C')   
    G = z.count('G')   
    T = z.count('T')
    sumbases = "A,C,G,T" # I suppose you format it here differently
    y = sumbases.replace("\n"," ")  # not sure why you need this

    # print(y) # don't print now, print later...
    output_lines.append(y)

print(','.join(output_lines))
```

**EDIT** for your edited question:

```
seq = input("enter DNA sequence to search: ")
pat = re.compile('(.{10})(ATC.{3,6}CAG)')
output_lines = [] 
for mat in pat.finditer(seq):
    x = mat.end()
    z = (mat.groups()+(seq[x:x+10],)[1]
    output_lines.append(str([z.count(a) for a in 'ACGT')]))
print(','.join(output_lines))
```

Comment: Nevermind my `print(y, end=',')` suggestion - it adds an ugly trailing comma. This is better, although it would be even better if the whole loop could be folded into a generator expression.

Comment: thanks for the help.  i don't think the print statement is supported in python 3 with this syntax? when i try this i get an error?

Comment: @sebrowns - sorry, just put brackets around it (see my edited answer). Also, if you write 'I get an error' on stackoverflow.com, then try to include it into your comment.

Comment: @sebrowns that's right. This example is for Python 2. But it's still not clear what your actual code is.

Comment: great. i think i am starting to understand now. i get a syntax error from output_lines on the penultimate line though.